# Symfony 4 htaccess

Tags: php, symfony

Ok, i fixed all the problem, configured the server on localhost, but i want to hide the /public directory and want to display the content in the root folder of my document for example `/forum/` and for logging `/forum/login` instead of going to `forum/public/login`. Here is the htaccess file but it dont work, because it gives `No routes for GET /forum/`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

What im doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you check the doc of symfony routing? You don't have to use htaccess https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

Comment: I need htacces because i dont want to access in public directory, i want the content to be displayed on the project rood dir, not inside in public.

Comment: All of this can be set in symfony's routing

Comment: Nope i tried with /forum/index etc in routing and it gives the same thing. Tried also with cache clearing and again i got that no route error.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the directories public and moving into the htdocs in localhost. Then edited the index.php and giving the correct path to the ENV and vendor autoload.

Comment: .. a slight aside .. why would you want to lock down the pub dir? what are you storing in there?!

Answer (score 1):

Actually sometimes we may need to add .htaccess file

We can use this code as .htaccess file. I have checked this on Ubuntu VPS and also on Cpanel.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

My root .htaccess looks like this, I think you can put it onto your symfony root folder.

```
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteEngine on

# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

Then my .htaccess inside the `public/` folder:

```
# Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
# If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
# project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
# resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
# work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
# the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

# Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
# (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
# rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
# endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front  controller ->
# redirect -> request -> ...).
# So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
# to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
# environment variable, you have 2 choices:
# - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
# - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
#   following RewriteCond (best solution)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```